# Regex - Capture group IP address

Tags: regex

I am attempting to parse some logs that contain a string with an IPAddr:port

Example:

> Client IP address: 192.168.1.10:47600

I am looing to extract the IP address only

This is as far as I got, but would like to omit the colon.

```
Client\s+IP\s+address:\s+([^ ]+:)
```

[Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/Vxu1n1/1)

Comment: Change `[^ ]` to `[^ :]`

Comment: Or use `[\d.]+` to match only numbers and `.`.

Comment: Move the colon outside of the group, `Client\s+IP\s+address:\s+([^ ]+):`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Client\s+IP\s+address:\s+(\S+):
```

**Details**

- `Client\s+IP\s+address:` - `Client IP address:` with any one or more whitespaces between the words
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars
- `:` - a colon.